# Qual dependência do Demoiselle 3 deve ser incluída em um projeto Maven para uso de JSF?

Tags: java, demoiselle

Tenho várias aplicações construídas com Demoiselle 2.4.2+JSF+PrimeFaces+Hibernate e gostaria de avançar para Demoiselle 3. Na portal dedicado a esta versão (http://demoiselle.io/) existe um exemplo de dependência Maven, como visto a seguir:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.demoiselle.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-parent-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

Neste exemplo trata-se de uma aplicação em modelo REST, que não é o caso do nosso legado. Outros links e páginas do mesmo portal estão quebrados, nos impossibilitando de encontrar outros exemplos.

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nosso portal está sendo refatorado e dentro de alguns dias estará corrigido o problema, obrigado por avisar.

Na versão 3, focamos no desenvolvimento de microserviços, devido a viabilidade econômica trazida por esse tipo de desenvolvimento e adaptação a estruturas de nuvem, com docker, multitenancy, etc. Durante a fase de debates internos e com a comunidade e munidos de vários testes de performance mais a adaptação das apps Restful em ambientes produtivos modernos, nos ajudou a decidirmos que o JSF não seria mais o foco da nova versão do framework. Sabemos de todas as coisas boas que o JSF nos proporcionou e como essa tecnologia impulsionou o mundo JEE6, apesar de não ser mais o foco do projeto, o JSF pode ser integrado a qualquer projeto com Demoiselle3 a qualquer momento, pois tudo é JEE, e se houver contribuições da comunidade para um componente JSF faremos a disponibilização em um repo dedicado a isso. Hoje ainda temos centenas de apps Demoiselle 2.x (JEE6 com JSF), só na empresa que trabalhamos, mas os ganhos trazidos pela versão 2.5(início do uso do paradigma) e agora com a 3.0, usando o paradigma REST/HTML5 são tão grandes que preferimos apoiar as equipes na evolução tecnológica mais viável e rentável. Sugerimos, caso seja possível, que você faça essa evolução, temos uma documentação que estamos constantemente melhorando que pode ajudar você nesse desafio.

Aqui tem a documentação mais atual
https://www.gitbook.com/@demoiselle

no http://demoiselle.org/jee7
Concentra os principais links do projeto JEE7

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Apenas para ficar absolutamente claro (tenho um relatório técnico a fazer): *hoje* o suporte a JSF para Demoiselle 3 ainda precisa ser desenvolvido, certo?